# How to pass string array as BSTR* to web service proxy

Tags: c++, web-services, arrays, bstr

In VS2005 I have generated a web reference to a web service that takes a 1-dimensional array of strings ("inputArray") as an input parameter.

The proxy function generated for this web service call asks for two parameters:

```
BSTR *inputArray
int inputArray_nSizeIs
```

What is the proper syntax for passing in inputArray as a BSTR*?  Currently I'm declaring it thusly:

```
BSTR inputArray = SysAllocString(L"{'account_name', 'user_name', 'date_time'}");
```

But this is being parsed improperly when generating the SOAP response in atlsoap.h.

Answer (score 2):

```
BSTR inputArray[3];
inputArray[0] = SysAllocString(L"account_name");
inputArray[1] = SysAllocString(L"user_name");
inputArray[2] = SysAllocString(L"date_time");
```